# Forge viewer: How to disable transparancy at Materials

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

In order to set colors upon many objects in the forge viewer, I made an extension which sets the color upon material and connect the objects to it. This way I only update the viewer once instead of multiple times. However I would like to have no transparancy, but I keep on getting it, even I have set the material transparancy to false. How can I fix this?

```
void setColorMaterial(material, viewer) 
{
    var mesh_material = this.addMaterial(material, viewer)

    for (var i=0; i< material.dbIds.length; i++) {
        var dbid = material.dbIds[i]

        var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree
        it.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragId) {
            var renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId)
        renderProxy.meshProxy = new THREE.Mesh(renderProxy.geometry, renderProxy.material)
        renderProxy.meshProxy.matrix.copy(renderProxy.matrixWorld)
        renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true
        renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixAutoUpdate = false
        renderProxy.meshProxy.frustumCulled = false
        viewer.impl.addOverlay(material.name, renderProxy.meshProxy)
      }, false)
    }
    this.materialHolder.push(material)
    viewer.impl.invalidate(true)
}

void addMaterial(material, viewer) 
{
    var mesh_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: #007dfa,
        opacity: 1,
        transparent: false,
        name: 'materialName'
})
    viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(this.newGuid(), mesh_material)
    viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(material.name, mesh_material, mesh_material)
}
```

Comment: remove opacity: 1

Comment: I don't see your `addMaterial ` is returning the opaque material you created nor is your `mesh_material` being applied to the objects added to the overlay?

Comment: Bryan: I fixed the code in according to your suggestions (as I understood them). Updated code is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you for your replies, unfortunately the transparancy is still there.

Alex: I removed the opacity.

Bryan: I fixed the code in according to your suggestions (as I understood them). Below is updated code.

As you can see from the picture in the link that the transparancy is still there. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
setColorMaterial(material, viewer) {
    var mesh_material = this.addMaterial(material, viewer)

    for (var i=0; i< material.dbIds.length; i++) {
        var dbid = material.dbIds[i]

        //from dbid to node, to fragid
        var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree
        it.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragId) {
            var renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId)
            renderProxy.meshProxy = new THREE.Mesh(renderProxy.geometry, mesh_material)
            renderProxy.meshProxy.matrix.copy(renderProxy.matrixWorld)
            renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true
            renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixAutoUpdate = false
            renderProxy.meshProxy.frustumCulled = false
            viewer.impl.addOverlay(material.name, renderProxy.meshProxy)
        }, false)
    }
    viewer.impl.invalidate(true)
}

addMaterial(material, viewer) {
  var mesh_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: material.color,
      transparent: false,
      blendEquationAlpha: false,
      name: material.name
  })
  viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(this.newGuid(), mesh_material)
  viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(material.name, mesh_material)
  return mesh_material
}
```

[Transparency still there image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEhWU.png)

Comment: Try change `renderProxy.meshProxy = new THREE.Mesh(renderProxy.geometry, mesh_material)` to `THREE.Mesh(renderProxy.geometry, renderProxy.material)` because an overriding material has already been passed in when the overlay is created.

Comment: I found the bug, the fault was in viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(material.name, mesh_material, mesh_material). I have now updated the code in the sample above, and it now works. Thanks for for your assistance.